# Using native lib (C only, no C++), and No Implementation Found

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

tried using [this lib](https://github.com/actorapp/droidkit-opus) for opus on android and AFAIK, the link and the .so look to be good.

ERROR on call to C function ( i followed [these intstructs](http://javapapers.com/core-java/how-to-call-a-c-program-from-java/)  )

```
D/OpusRecorder( 1964): Start recording!
E/art     ( 1964): No implementation found for int com.droidkit.opus.OpusLib.startRecord(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord and Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord__Ljava_lang_String_2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1964): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8227
E/AndroidRuntime( 1964): Process: com.borneo.speech, PID: 1964
E/AndroidRuntime( 1964): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.droidkit.opus.OpusLib.startRecord(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord and Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord__Ljava_lang_String_2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1964):    at com.droidkit.opus.OpusLib.startRecord(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1964):    at com.borneo.speech.OpusRecorder.run(OpusRecorder.java:439)
W/ActivityManager(  724):   Force finishing activity 1 com.borneo.speech/.Speech_API_Activity
```

The .so is packaged in apk

function exist in the .so with Type= "T"...

```
aar$ nm -D libopus.so | head
000084c1 T Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_closeOpusFile
000084c5 T Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_isOpusFile
00008491 T Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_openOpusFile
00008471 T Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_readOpusFile
00008489 T Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_seekOpusFile
00008145 T Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord ***
```

**---CLang details---**

implementation in C:

audio.c

```
#include "com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib.h"   <-- from the Java class=com.droidkit.opus.OpusLib via javah
```

//rev belo per @Nicklas

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis, jstring path) {
    const char *pathStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, path, 0);

    int result = initRecorder(pathStr);

    if (pathStr != 0) {
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, path, pathStr);
    }

    return result;
}
```

c headers...

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib */

#ifndef _Included_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib
#define _Included_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib
 * Method:    startRecord
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib
 * Method:    writeFrame
 * Signature: (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_writeFrame
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject, jint);

/*
 * Class:     com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib
 * Method:    stopRecord
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_stopRecord
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib
 * Method:    isOpusFile
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_isOpusFile
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**===JAVA Details Calls to C===**

==EDITED== Java Native Decl.

```
/**
 * OpusLib native binding
 */
public class OpusLib {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("opus");
    }

    /**
     * Starting opus recording
     *
     * @param path path to file
     * @return non zero if started player
     */
    public native int startRecord(String path);


    /**
     * Writing audio frame to encoder
     *
     * @param frame buffer with sound in 16 bit mono PCM 16000 format
     * @param len   len of data
     * @return not null if successful
     */
    public native int writeFrame(ByteBuffer frame, int len);

    /**
     * Stopping record
     */
    public native void stopRecord();

    /**
     * Checking Opus File format
     *
     * @param path path to file
     * @return non zero if opus file
     */
    public native int isOpusFile(String path);

    /**
     * Opening file
     *
     * @param path path to file
     * @return non zero if successful
     */
    public native int openOpusFile(String path);

    /**
     * Seeking in opus file
     *
     * @param position position in file
     * @return non zero if successful
     */
    public native int seekOpusFile(float position);

    /**
     * Closing opus file
     */
    public native void closeOpusFile();

    /**
     * Reading from opus file
     *
     * @param buffer
     * @param capacity
     */
    public native void readOpusFile(ByteBuffer buffer, int capacity);

    /**
     * Is playback finished
     *
     * @return non zero if playback is finished
     */
    public native int getFinished();

    /**
     * Read block size in readOpusFile
     *
     * @return block size in bytes
     */
    public native int getSize();

    /**
     * Offset of actual sound for playback
     *
     * @return offset
     */
    public native long getPcmOffset();

    /**
     * Total opus pcm duration
     *
     * @return pcm duration
     */
    public native long getTotalPcmDuration();

}

        try {
            opus = new OpusLib();
        }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError ulx) {
            Log.e(LTAG, "Illegal native Load: " + ulx.getMessage());
        }

...
public class OpusLib {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("opus");
    }
```

AFAIK , lib is getting loaded ok

UnsatisfiedLink Excp occurs on last line below:

private String  mPath = path;

```
   if (mShouldRecord)            
       int mint = opus.startRecord(mPath);     <-- throws unsatisfiedLink - no implementation found
```

startRecord is in the symbols table altho im not certain all the function parm types match up? see the "string_2"...

**startRecord__Ljava_lang_String_2)**

**==== Build info Gradle and linkedit ===**

```
link :
command: /usr/local/src/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/rob/src/tmp/speechnw/libraries/opus/build/intermediates/ndk/release/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=/home/rob/src/tmp/speechnw/libraries/opus/build/intermediates/ndk/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/rob/src/tmp/speechnw/libraries/opus/build/intermediates/ndk/release/lib APP_STL=stlport_static APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a

[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : opus <= audio.c                       
...
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libopus.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libopus.so => /home/rob/src/tmp/speechnw/libraries/opus/build/intermediates/ndk/release/lib/armeabi-v7a/libopus.so
```

build.gradle

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1.1"

```
ndk {
    moduleName "opus"

    cFlags "-DANDROID_NDK " +
            "-DDISABLE_IMPORTGL " +
            "-w -std=gnu99 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays " +
            "-DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 "+
            "-Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno "
            "-DAVOID_TABLES "
    ldLibs "log", "m"
    stl "stlport_static"
    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
}
```

}

Comment: Did you use `javah` to create the signatures?

Comment: Where do you declare that native method in your class?

Comment: Some suggestions - look for log messages at the time of native library loading, make sure you deployed the latest version of the native library, and trying merging the ndk sample hello-jni into your poject and see if *that* functionality still works (that last one can be really helpful - having working and unworking code side by side tends to highlight problems)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord(JNIEnv *env, jclass class, jstring path) {
```

with:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis, jstring path) {
```

The function you've defined in C maps to a static method in Java, but in Java you're using it as an instance method. What I've replaced is this: `jclass class,` with `jobject javaThis,` in your C function signature. Please also note that in your C headers you've also declared the functions with instance method signatures, just as it seems you're intending to.

Comment: You may have a point about subsequent functionality, but how would this explain the observed problem?  No argument type or count information is encoded in the shared library, so the dynamic linker has no means of differentiating between static and instance methods, other than by hoping the names are used consistently.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - *" the dynamic linker has no means of differentiating between static and instance methods, other than by hoping the names are used consistently"* -  its well defined, and `javah` encodes that in the signature. See, for example, [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/jni.html).

Comment: @Nicklas thanks. your explain makes sense but ...  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis, jstring path)   -->   same error in logcat ...   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.droidkit.opus.OpusLib.startRecord(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord and Java_com_droidkit_opus_OpusLib_startRecord__Ljava_lang_String_2)

Comment: @jww - no, that is not the case, argument signatures do not end up in the shared library. Look for yourself at the method names for the native methods implementations in the `nm` output - that is all that is available to the dynamic linker - **no argument type information present at all**.  Anything else is purely the vm confusing *itself* - ie, not the fault of the C code.  That's distinct from the question of the method failing once linked - the problem right now is that it is not being linked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thx. re "not being linked" . Maybe i should go back to using explicit Android.mk instead of the integrated gradle DSL for ndk{}  . I've never tried an AStudio type android ndk build using the default DSL task for ndk.. Have always use 'ph0b's' method for AS-ndk. The git module had it this way so i went with it?  http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: I was speaking of dynamic linking, which happens at runtime (ie, the vm process needing to find the native method in the shared library, which is failing), not static linking at buildtime.  You posted code is critically missing the declaration of the native method in your java class.  Include it in your question.  Do you by any chance have more than one method by that name in the class?

Comment: Java Native Declare added to java section of OP

Comment: 10K foot view.. if this is brittle implementation , i can just shelve it.   I saw the android-opus lib on github and thought i would try todo opus codecs on android using the lib... If there is not a good way to use without building a .cpp wrapper for it, I can wait for someone else to do it.

Comment: In actuality, the "wrong" version here won't even make a functional difference as a jclass is a typedef of jobject and thus the same size, and that misidentified argument is unused in the implementation of the method.